# What are the resonating structures of toluene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

I initially made the resonating structures by first converting toluene into a toluene carbocation. But the resonating structures of a neutral molecule should be neutral. So what are the correct resonating structures of toluene?

Answer (score 1):

The resonances in toluene should be roughly the same as in benzene, because it is hard to believe that no bond or a double bond may occur by resonance between the phenyl cycle and the methyl group, whatever the situation in the rest of the molecule.

Answer (score 0):

The motion of electrons inside the benzene ring is a component of the resonance structures in toluene. Toluene contains a methyl group (-CH3) attached to the benzene ring. The benzene ring's pi electrons are uniformly distributed in the major resonance structure, resulting in an arrangement of alternating single and double bonds. As a result of the electron density delocalization, a more stable configuration is produced.

The double bonds are displayed around the benzene ring in various positions in the minor resonance structures. These structures however, add less to the overall picture of toluene and are therefore less significant. The electrons in the pi bonds are distributed throughout the whole benzene ring rather than being fixed in one place, which results in a more stable and even distribution of electron density.

Toluene is a combination of all these resonance structures. The molecule's nature can be described as a resonance hybrid, as the electronic structure is a combination of these forms.